# ActionBarSherlock hardkey menu panel text color

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I have a small question about theming my app that uses ActionBarSherlock. Everything works fine except on `Samsung phones with TouchWizz`. The overflow menu items appear by pressing the hardware menu key.

I know how to change the panel background. My default theme extends `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`, so the default menu item text color in the hardware panel will be `black`, I wan't to change this.

Any ideas on how to do this besides changing the parent of my default theme?

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:panelBackground">@drawable/menu_hardkey_panel</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the correct attrs to tune hardware menu style.
You should look at *panelColorForeground* ;-)

```
<item name="android:panelColorBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
<item name="android:panelColorForeground">@color/primary_text_holo_dark</item>
<item name="android:panelFullBackground">@drawable/menu_background_fill_parent_width_holo_dark</item>
<item name="android:panelTextAppearance">@style/Holo.TextAppearance</item>
```

*Tested on HoloEverywhere lib and 2.3 emulator.*
See [attrs doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#panelColorBackground) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do, but if you want to change textColor in this panel you can create custom style with parent set to TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu and then change textColor property. Like this:

```
<style name="Widget.MyApp.ActionBarPopupLargeTextColor" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyApp.ActionBarPopupSmallTextColor" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Worked for me :)